# If I discover a breakthrough for my company should I expect to have a share in it?

Tags: startup, compensation, behavior

As a full time employee for only 1.5 years in a start-up, I may have found a breakthrough that could help the company be a leader in a certain application. If this turns out to be a breakthrough how should I behave?

Comment: Your contract or any IP assignments you signed will tell you. VTC.

Comment: You should not expect to get an extra share in a work product that is part of your job.

Answer (score 11):

I'm sorry for being brutal, but it sounds as though you are performing the job that the company pays you to do.

The usual process would be:

- You complete an IP disclosure and submit it to your manager.
- Your manager asks your colleagues to confirm the result.
- The company files a patent naming you as inventor and itself as beneficiary.
- Life continues as usual.

You want the company founders get think of you as a useful person so that they ask you to buy in at the startup their next venture.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response. This is my first job, I don't know the formalities. I shared my recent possible success with a friend and he told me to ask about shares. I think it would be nice to have shares, but at the end of the day it would be from the presidents generosity wouldn't it? Should I ask about it anyway?

Comment: You can always ask, but they are under no obligation to respond. They already own the code that you wrote.

Comment: Depending on your jurisdiction that may be no so clear - Germany and some other EU-countries have stuff like "Arbeitnehmererfindung" (German) which grants the inventor some rights/compensation when inventing stuff on the job.

Comment: But if you keep doing it, they might to be very interested in giving you a raise.

Comment: Good answer. In large US companies, being associated with a patent is a big deal, and it does contribute to your "stickiness" at the company, as well as your marketability when looking for other work. Even though you may not share directly in the revenue it might generate, you do benefit indirectly from your invention.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the nature of any employment agreements you have signed.  If this breakthrough was done on company time, you most likely are doing your job and will not have an additional stake in it.  It certainly would not hurt to ask though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is software development. I would hazard a guess that in your contract there will be a clause about Intellectual Property, and that it's likely that it will belong to the company.

If you leave it until it's finished, then you won't have a leg to stand on legally.

If it's such a big thing, then you need to discuss it with the owners. I'm not sure how well this would/wouldn't go down. But even then, I just think you can use it in your next pay review for a large raise/bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the nature of the startup.

Also the first thing is for you to decide:-

1. Whether the breakthrough is so different that you can make your own mark (with your unique work which is not done at existing startup premises). - In this case, you can provide all the details of the work done to the partners, pack your bags and leave.
2. Or you are so passionate about it and hence, can take the partners into confidence to either provide you with a share or a partner. In this case, become a partner in the startup (delayed indulgence).
3. Or if you will be happy to work with a startup with some compensation (like a bonus). In this case, you can talk to your boss (decision maker for your bonus) about it.

The best will be that you discuss the breakthrough briefly with partners.

Comment: I think I will wait until all testing is finished and if it is a breakthrough I will talk with the founder and partner.